# Number of triangles.

Tags: geometry

How to find the number of non degenerate triangles in the Cartesian plane whose vertices lie in the set$ \{(x, y) : 0\le x\le7  , 0\le y\le7\}$ .
I don't have any idea how to solve it...

Answer (score 1):

You have $64$ points in your set, so ignoring the degenerate condition there are $64\choose 3$ triangles.  For a triangle to be degenerate, the three points need to be on the same line, so find all the lines that have three or more points on them and subtract the number of ways to select three from one of them.

Comment: How to find those lines which have three or more points in common

Comment: @user364168 As a thought to work on, any line that goes through at least two points in a [0..3,0..3] lattice will go through at least three in a [0..7,0..7] lattice.

Comment: And how to find that?

Comment: Try drawing a $5 \times 5$ grid and look at it.  Some of the degenerate triangles are horizontal or vertical.  Others are on a slope.  Think about how the slopes happen and how many there will be in your $8 \times 8$ grid.

Comment: Have you driven by an orchard and seen how the trees line up?  That should be the sort of thing you are thinking about.

Comment: @user364168 any two points define a line.

Comment: I am not able to generalize any of your statements....... Can you please provide an answer which i can verify....

Comment: Did you try drawing a smaller grid as I suggested?  Think about $(0,1),(1,3),(2,5)$

Comment: Okay.... But how to find the exact number..... Isn't there any way to compute.....

Comment: @user364168 just to show you are thinking about this and following along, can you calculate how many degenerate triangles there will be [among the $\binom{64}{3}$ selections] where the line the three points are on is the x-axis? And how many on a line parallel to the x-axis?